# Elasticsearch - Reindex Picks Up No Documents using official documentation

Tags: elasticsearch

I am following reindex documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-migrate-data.html

I have two Elasticsearch indexes in localhost:

192.168.0.100:9200

```
{
  "name" : "fses01",
  "cluster_name" : "fs-es-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "DqVDBBafRaO9UAJPKuc_xQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.14.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "dd5a0a2acaa2045ff9624f3729fc8a6f40835aa1",
    "build_date" : "2021-07-29T20:49:32.864135063Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.9.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

With the following index:

```
health status index             uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   formshare_records NpEFzsGvTEmivnYjJhwHJg   5   1      51343            0      7.8mb          3.9mb
```

192.168.0.100:9201

```
{
  "name" : "es01",
  "cluster_name" : "es-docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "bvsRXLwZRtKuWIrIuKx0hg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.14.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "6bc13727ce758c0e943c3c21653b3da82f627f75",
    "build_date" : "2021-09-15T10:18:09.722761972Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.9.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

With the same index but blank:

```
health status index             uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   formshare_records uxvizIAIS82YBHSsvpq4-Q   5   1          0            0        2kb            1kb
```

I am doing a reindex using CULR with the following:

```
curl -X POST "192.168.0.100:9201/_reindex" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://192.168.0.100:9200"      
    },
    "index": "formshare_records",
    "query": {
      "match_all": {}
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "formshare_records"
  }
}
'
```

But I get zero transfer:

```
{"took":34,"timed_out":false,"total":0,"updated":0,"created":0,"deleted":0,"batches":0,"version_conflicts":0,"noops":0,"retries":{"bulk":0,"search":0},"throttled_millis":0,"requests_per_second":-1.0,"throttled_until_millis":0,"failures":[]}
```

The index definition is the same on both sides:

```
{"settings": {
            "index": {
                "number_of_shards": 5,
                "number_of_replicas": 1
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "project_id": {"type": "keyword"},
                "form_id": {"type": "keyword"},
                "schema": {"type": "keyword"},
                "table": {"type": "keyword"}
            }
        }}
```

Both of them are under docker:
192.168.0.100:9200

```
version: '3'
services:
  fses01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.0
    container_name: fses01
    environment:
      - node.name=fses01
      - cluster.name=fs-es-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=fses02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=fses01,fses02
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m"
      - cluster.max_shards_per_node=20000
      - script.max_compilations_rate=10000/1m
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - /opt/elasticsearch-docker/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  fses02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.0
    container_name: fses02
    environment:
      - node.name=fses02
      - cluster.name=fs-es-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=fses01
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=fses01,fses02
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m"
      - cluster.max_shards_per_node=20000
      - script.max_compilations_rate=10000/1m   
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - /opt/elasticsearch-docker/data2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet
  kib01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.14.0
    container_name: kib01
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://fses01:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: '["http://fses01:9200","http://fses02:9200"]'
    networks:
        - esnet
networks:
  esnet:
```

192.168.0.100:9201

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.2
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - reindex.remote.whitelist=192.168.0.100:9200
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - /opt/elasticsearch710/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9201:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.2
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - /opt/elasticsearch710/data2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic
  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.2
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - /opt/elasticsearch710/data3:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic
networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

The container of 9201 can see the index of 9200:

```
sudo docker exec -it es01 /bin/bash
[root@943159977b17 elasticsearch]# curl -X GET "192.168.0.100:9200/_cat/indices/formshare_records?v&s=index&pretty"
health status index             uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   formshare_records NpEFzsGvTEmivnYjJhwHJg   5   1      51343            0      7.8mb          3.9mb
curl -X POST "192.168.0.100:9201/_reindex" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://192.168.0.100:9200"      
    },
    "index": "formshare_records",        
    "query": {
      "match_all": {}
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "formshare_records"
  }
}
'
{"took":18,"timed_out":false,"total":0,"updated":0,"created":0,"deleted":0,"batches":0,"version_conflicts":0,"noops":0,"retries":{"bulk":0,"search":0},"throttled_millis":0,"requests_per_second":-1.0,"throttled_until_millis":0,"failures":[]}
```

Any idea why reindex does not work? I tried without query but I get the same!

Comment: Hi, What is the network mode of your second elastic node which is up using docker?

Comment: Hi, I added the YMLs of both servers

Comment: well, when you send your request to elasticsearch on port 9201 from your server and say the remote server is localhost:9200, it see this localhost in its own container. I mean that localhost:9200 in your second docker is itself. You need to change your network mode to host or put both of the containers in the same network and put the service name instead of localhost in your reindex query.

Comment: Instead of localhost, I changed to the IP address of my machine (192.168.0.100). I entered into the docker container running 9201. And I did: [root@943159977b17 elasticsearch]# curl -X GET "192.168.0.100:9200/_cat/indices/formshare_records?v&s=index&pretty"
health status index             uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   formshare_records NpEFzsGvTEmivnYjJhwHJg   5   1      51343            0      7.8mb          3.9mb
[root@943159977b17 elasticsearch]#   I can see the index of 9200 with 51343 docs but the result is the same.

Comment: Even if I tried inside the container of 9201 fails

Comment: After doing this, did you put that as whitelist in es 9201?

Comment: Yes. I updated the whitelist of 9201. See updated question

Comment: Sorry, it works!!!! I introduced by mistake a type in the reindex..... Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Great! Glad to hear that. You’re welcome, my friend.